# SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import after npm install sass-loader

Tags: css, node.js, npm, webpack, sass

I have this directory structure:

[image]

Inside `layout/UserPanel.vue`:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "../../scss/colors.scss";
...
```

**It used to work fine**, but after I run (following some tutorial)

```
npm install sass sass-loader fibers deepmerge -D
```

It broke and there was an error

[image]

I tried rolling back:

```
npm uninstall sass sass-loader fibers deepmerge -D
```

```
npm install sass-loader sass webpack --save-dev
```

but the error remains